# Accessing property of constructor without creating new instance

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to access properties of a constructor object/function **without first creating an instance from it**?

For example, let's say I have this constructor:

```js
function Cat() {
  this.legs = 4;
};
```

And now – **without creating a new cat instance** – I want to know what value of `legs` is inside the constructor. Is this possible?

(And I'm not looking for stuff like: `var legs = new Cat().legs`. (Let's say the instantiation of a new Cat is super CPU expensive for some reason.))

Comment: Maybe declare it outside of constructor, since it's hard-coded anyway? Then you can pass it to constructor, and also access it outside of it.

Comment: You could chain Cat: `function Cat() { this.legs = 4; return this; }` => `Cat().legs`. But you still need those "CPU Cycles" to run the function

Comment: Many things are possible, some of them don't even make sense :). Call `Cat.toString()` and parse the result.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! To make my question make more sense: let's say there are a bunch of different cat breed names which I want to store inside the Cat prototype and then access just out of curiosity "hmmm I wonder what kinds of breeds are available?", without creating a new cat just for this purpose.

Comment: Anything inside `Cat` only exists during the execution of the function (and possibly after if it is returned from the function). So you either have to store the data outside of the function or you are looking for statically analysis. There is not enough context to provide a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, that makes sense. My use case (context) is a bit too complex to properly explain here, but thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Does something like this count?

```
function Cat() {
  this.legs = 4;
}

var obj = {};
Cat.call(obj);
console.log(obj.legs); // 4
```

Comment: This avoids creating a new instance only superficially. It won't avoid the "super CPU expensive" instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, `leg` is an instance variable, which means that an object instance is needed in order to access it.

You can make it a pseudo-`class variable` (see [class variable in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641229/class-variable-in-javascript)), you should be able then to access it without calling the function (instantiating the object).

Comment: Can I somehow (in a clean way) not make legs an instance variable? I guess binding it to `this` is what does it, but what are my options?

Comment: @KristofferK—move *legs* outside the constructor: `var legs = 12; function Cat(){ this.legs = legs; ...};`

Comment: @KristofferK: I updated my answer with suggestion about class variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is even more expensive:

```
console.log(parseInt(Cat.toString().match(/this\.legs\s*=\s*(\d+)/)[1]));
```

Comment: Especially as *match* may return *null*, and `null[1]` will throw an error. ;-)

Comment: Yes, you need to know that the member is actually there and that it's a number

Answer (score 1):

There's a hundred ways to do this, but the static default pattern below is as good as any of them:

```
function Cat(opts) {
  var options = opts || {};
  this.legs == options.legs || Cat.defaults.legs;
};

Cat.defaults = {
  legs: 4
}

var myCat = new Cat({legs:3}); //poor guy
var normalNumberOfCatLegs = Cat.defaults.legs;
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, no you can't access that variable without creating an instance of it, but you can work around it:

**Global Variable**

Assuming 'legs' may vary as the application runs, you may want to create a "global" variable by assigning legs to 'window', an object that will exist throughout the life of the page:

```
window.legs = 4; // put this at the top of your script
```

Then throughout the course of the application, you can change this until you're ready to use it in Cats():

```
window.legs = user_input;
```

**Global Object**

You could even assign an object to window, if you want Cats to have other, alterable attributes:

```
window.Cat = {};
window.Cat.legs = 4;
window.Cat.has_tail = true;
window.Cat.breeds = ["siamese","other cat breed"];
```

**How to use Globals**

Then, when a Cat object is created later on, you can pull the data from window to create an instance of Cat:

```
function Cat(){
  this.legs = window.legs;
  //or
  this.legs = window.Cat.legs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, the global/outside storing of the data is probably what I'll end up doing, but what I would love is to just have all of this in one place (preferably inside the constructor function). But there is probably something flawed in this ambition, and I probably need to rethink it. Thanks again.

Comment: @ Kristoffer K what do you say about `Amir Popovich` answer

Comment: The @Amir Popovich Answer still creates an instance of Cat. This technically does not.

Answer (score -3):

```
// cat.js
function Cat() {

}

Cat.prototype.legs = 4;

// somescript.js
var legs = Cat.prototype.legs
var cat = new Cat();
console.log(legs, cat.legs); // 4, 4
```